Cannot limit TileLayer with minZoom in ol-cesium
I have a map created with OpenLayers and ol-cesium.
I have created a tile layer that should only appear after a certain zoom level:
return new TileLayer({
    minZoom: minZoom,
    source: new XYZ({
        url: ...
    })
});

This works fine in 2D, but when I switch to 3D mode (Cesium), the layer shows in every zoom level.
Is there a way to get Cesium to follow the minimum zoom level for a tile layer?
Is this a limitation or bug in Cesium or in ol-cesium, or do I need to do anything differently?

Layer minZoom refers to view zoom level, not the tile grid zoom level.  That can be demonstrated by setting a minZoom in a example such as https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/projection-and-scale.html - the layer may appear or disappear when changing the view to a different projection.  3d mode zooms may not relate an OpenLayers view.  Instead you could restrict tile zoom using the source minZoom option (that could result in a huge number of minZoom level tiles being loaded when zoomed out) or prevent low zoom level tiles being loaded by discarding them in a tileUrlFunction:
const defaultTileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction();
source.setTileUrlFunction(([z, x, y]) =>
  z > minZoom ? defaultTileUrlFunction([z, x, y]) : undefined,
);

Instead of discarding with undefined you could use a transparent data url
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 1;
canvas.height = 1;
const defaultUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
const defaultTileUrlFunction = source.getTileUrlFunction();
source.setTileUrlFunction(([z, x, y]) =>
  z > minZoom ? defaultTileUrlFunction([z, x, y]) : defaultUrl,
);


This solution works partially. It succeeds in preventing loading the tiles over the minZoom. However, once the tile is loaded, if you zoom out the layer does not hide, so you see squares with the areas that have been previously zoomed in.

Using a transparent data url instead of undefined might work better in that situation, I have added to the answer.

This works beautifully
